# Re-using vertexes is fine but what to do with the texture coordinates?

Tags: opengl

I know that if I create a cube with a vertex array I can reuse the vertexes by using an index array ( 8 vertexes for the cube and then an array of 36 indexes ( two triangles per side of the cube )). This works correctly when passed to glDrawElements.

However what I am not clear on is what to do with the texture coordinates. Is there an equivalent way of passing a reduced list of texture coordinates ( again 8 of them for my cube ) with an index to guide OpenGL, or is there some other method I need to employ ?

I am using the fixed pipeline for this so I cannot use a shader for this.

Comment: I think you're mistaking what what indices are for. They aren't the number one solution to reduce vertices. Basically only use indices if you have a lot of duplicated vertices, in the case that you don't, then using indices would be a waste. ... You wouldn't be able to use indices in the same way, when you also need to have texture coordinates. Why? because, now a lot of the vertices aren't shared anymore, as each corner have (or might have) different texture coordinates.

Comment: This explains why I have never found a solution to this by hunting around in the OpenGL books. Thank you

Comment: Thereby if you have a lot of "shared vertices" or in other words "duplicated vertices" then use indices (`glDrawElements()`), if you don't, then don't use indices (`glDrawArrays()`)

Comment: Thats a very good idea. I guess that way I can ditch all the indexes. Its probably quicker too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even with shaders you need to match position and texture coordinate to each other in the buffers; in other words if the position is at index 0 then the texture coordinate **must** also be at index 0

you can unwrap the texture so you can reuse some vertices but you won't be able to reuse all. if you don't do any special unwrapping you need to have 6*4=24 vertices, this is still much better than 36

Comment: I have of late become paranoid about the number of vertexes in my buffers and so I thought this would be the logical step forward, to reduce them. Based on this feedback I shall return to having duplicate vertexes so that I can keep it nicely correlated with my texture coordinates ( whether I specify them or generate them with a shader ) even though this may add some additional overhead. Thank you